# Android - adb logcat works only on shell

Tags: android, adb

When I run `adb logcat` nothing happens but when I run it in the adb shell then it works ok.
Those are the outputs:

```
eduardo@debian:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
LGM250CE6PYLFQGU9P  device

eduardo@debian:~$ adb -s LGM250CE6PYLFQGU9P logcat -t 1
eduardo@debian:~$ adb -s LGM250CE6PYLFQGU9P shell -t "logcat -t 1"
--------- beginning of main
09-12 20:52:09.511   380   380 I DisplayDevice: [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:1.987004,dur:1006.54,max:515.21,min:491.33
eduardo@debian:~$
```

And this is my adb version.

```
eduardo@debian:~$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4986621
Installed as /home/eduardo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

The same behavior happens on Windows and Debian.

Is it something wrong with adb or my device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue when I upgraded platform-tools from 28.0.0 to 28.0.1 on Debian and Windows yesterday.

By seeing your **Android Debug Bridge** version and the date of your question, I suppose you have upgraded your `platform-tools` to 28.0.1.

You can try to do a workaround: downgrade your `platform-tools` to 28.0.0.

1. Download the `platform-tools` 28.0.0 from Google's android repository

   - Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-linux.zip
   - Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip
2. Unzip **platform-tools_r28.0.0-*.zip** and try to run the `adb` from platform-tools/adb
3. If it works, you can overwrite your current Android SDK's `platform-tools` by copying the unzipped `platform-tools` folder into your Android SDK Root directory
4. Try to avoid `platform-tools` to update to 28.0.1 again until this issue is solved

## Update

After reading the link in the comment of @Eduardo, it seems that `platform-tools 28.0.1` exposed a bug on LG devices when running `adb logcat`.

The maintainer of `adb` suggested the following workaround if you want to run newer versions of `platform-tools`:

Use `adb shell -x logcat` instead of `adb logcat`.

Comment: It is working fine now. This bug is causing problems with flutter debugging and I used your solution as its solution here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18889#issuecomment-421432066    
thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, @Eduardo, I updated my answer.